# What does 'E chu ta' mean?

Tags: star-wars, droids, the-empire-strikes-back

A protocol droid on Cloud City (E-3PO) says this to C-3PO. If C-3PO's reaction is any indication it was either an insult or an obscenity.

**Does anyone know a translated version of this word/phrase?**

Comment: It means "Han shot first". Which we all know is very rude to say... to George Lucas.

Comment: @machavity http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/7/79/Kelly_and_George.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20070902054422

Answer (score 36):

We don't know, but it's very (*very*) rude.

> *“E chu ta!” replies the droid.
>
>   C-3PO stops, stunned. “How rude!”
>
>   (**“E chu ta,” is, of course, Huttese. It is absolutely not appropriate to translate. Maybe when you’re older.**)*
>
> <sup><sub>[The Empire Strikes Back: So You Want to be a Jedi?](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back:_So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Jedi%3F)</sub></sup>

According to wookieepedia, this theme (of the phrase being simply *too obscene to translate*) is apparently continued in Ben Burtt's '[Galactic Phrase Book and Travel Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Phrase_Book_%26_Travel_Guide_(real-life_book))' (the in-universe translator [Ebenn Q3 Baoban](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ebenn_Q3_Baobab) refused to translate it) as well as in the new '[Star Wars: Legacy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Legacy)' comics where it's simply described as an insult and the old [Databank article on E-3PO](http://web.archive.org/web/20110911024817/http://www.starwars.com/databank/droid/e3po/index.html) where his words were referred to as

> *a scathing invective*.